# Having an issue with Pillow coordinates (PIL)

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, discord.py

I'm having a issue and struggling to understand how PIL (Pillow) coordinates work for shapes more specifically ellipses. I'm wanting to move an ellipse to a certain placement of an image. When I try to change to coordinates it just stretches and contorts so far this is what I've managed.

The size ratio of the ellipse is 128 height x 128 width + 40 this is what it looks like:
However, it's not in the preferred place I'd like it.

[image]

Here is one I did a mock up of in paint just as an example of where I'd like to place the ellipse.

[image]

Here is what I'm working with:

```
                # Avatar border
                w, h = (128, 128)
                im_draw.ellipse((28, 0, w + 40 + 28, h + 40), fill=f"{ctx.message.author.color}")
```

> Full Code below

```
                im = Image.new("RGBA", (900, 296), (44, 44, 44, 255))
                im_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
                f = discord.File(f"progress_bar.png", f"progress_bar.png")

                # User name
                im_draw.text((350, 15), ctx.message.author.display_name, font=self.medium_font, fill=(255, 255, 255, 255))

                # Level
                lvl_text = f"LEVEL {lvl}"
                im_draw.text((350, 74), lvl_text, font=self.medium_font, fill=(255, 255, 255, 255))

                
                # XP Progress Text
                xp_text2 = f"{human_format(xp)} / {human_format(round(need_xp - xp))} XP"
                im_draw.text((30, 224), xp_text2, font=self.xsmall_font, fill=(255, 255, 255, 255))

                # XP progress bar
                progress = xp / round((500 + 100 * lvl))
                
                img = self.round_rectangle((895, 20), 0, (64, 64, 64, 255))
                im.paste(img, (2, 275), img)

                img2 = self.round_rectangle((int(895 * progress), 20), 0, fill=f"{ctx.message.author.color}")
                im.paste(img2, (2, 275), img2)

                # Avatar border
                w, h = (128, 128)
                im_draw.ellipse((28, 0, w + 40 + 28, h + 40), fill=f"{ctx.message.author.color}")

                
                 Avatar
                circle = Image.open("images/circle1.png")
                url = ctx.message.author.avatar_url
                response = requests.get(url)
                img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
                resize = img.resize((w, h))
                im.paste(resize, (48, 20), circle)
                
                im.save("progress_bar.png")
                await ctx.send(file=f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first argument of `ellipse()` is `(28, 0, w + 40 + 28, h + 40)`. These are the coordinates of the so-called bounding box, see [docs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-imagedraw-draw-ellipse/). It is in the shape of `[x0, y0, x1, y1]`, or in other words: the left most point, the top most point, the right most point and the bottom most point. In your case, x0=28 and y0=0, and hence the circle is at the top of your image and probably too much to the left.

If you want to have an ellipse at center point `(x, y)` of size `(w, h)`, this is what you need:

```
w, h = (128, 128)
x, y = (28, 54)
x0 = x - int(round(w/2))
x1 = x0 + w
y0 = y - int(round(h/2))
y1 = y + h
im_draw.ellipse(xy=(x0, y0, x1, y1), fill=...)
```